# error: 50 - Local Database Runtime error occurred. Specified LocalDB instance name is invalid ON JETBRAIN RIDER

Tags: c#, sql-server, asp.net-mvc, rider

I'm trying to write ASP.NET core on Jetbrain Rider, but I'm stuck on this error though I configure all necessary settings to use SQL Server Express 2014.

Here is my connection string:

```
"Server=(localdb)\\SQLEXPRESS;Database=Library;Trusted_Connection=True;MultipleActiveResultSets=True"
```

And I successfully connected SQLEXPRESS instance on Microsoft SQL Management Studio

I also passed my connection string to UseSQLServer method in OnConfiguring method of startup.cs
`optionsBuilder.UseSqlServer(@"Server=(localdb)\\SQLEXPRESS;Database=Library;Trusted_Connection=True;MultipleActiveResultSets=True");`

I'm stuck for 2 days on this error, I read almost all microsoft and Jetbrain related docs but it couldn't help

[image: Successfully connected on microsoft SQL Management Studio]

[image: The error I'm getting when i run dotnet ef database update from the command line]

Comment: SQL Server Express <> LocalDb.  Try `(local)\\SQLEXPRESS` as the Server in your connection string instead.  Or `abdullahi\\sqlexpress`.

Comment: Thank you, I tried both cases, the error is now instance failure, seems it will be more easy to resolve

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Modifying my connection string as [squillman](https://stackoverflow.com/users/75852/squillman) suggested and removing one backslash solved my problem. Here is how the connection string looks like:

```
@"Data Source=abdullahi\SQLEXPRESS;Database=Library;Trusted_Connection=True;MultipleActiveResultSets=True"
```

NOTE

1. I changed Server to Data Source
2. Changed the name of my instance and host to the actual SQL instance name and computer respectively.
3. Removed the escape backslash character because the entire string is preceded by @

Comment: This is the issue with double slash and @ combination, thanks!